# How would you solve $\int \frac{x}{x^2 - 4x + 5} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the tip for integrating that integral? I completed the square on the bottom to make it $$\frac{x}{(x-2)^2  + 1}$$

but it doesn't seem helpful. Any tips?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can continue by letting $u=x-2$, $x=u+2$, $dx=du$ to get

$\displaystyle\int\frac{u+2}{u^2+1} du=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2u}{u^2+1} du+2\int\frac{1}{u^2+1} du=\frac{1}{2}\ln(u^2+1)+2\arctan u + C$

$\;\;=\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2-4x+5)+2\arctan(x-2)+C$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

As $\dfrac{(x-2)^2}{dx}=2(x-2),$

write 
$$\frac x{(x-2)^2+1}=\frac{x-2}{(x-2)^2+1}+2\cdot\frac1{(x-2)^2+1}$$

We can use [Trigonometric substitution](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/integration/trigsub/trigsub.html)  $x-2=\tan\theta$ for the second part